# Accessing campaign field of lead

Tags: visualforce, leads, standard-objects, standardcontroller

I created a `Visualforce Page` to do some customization. First step of it is to access the fields. I am not able access `Campaign` field on the `Lead` object. I used the standard controller.

Comment: If you have a wish to get good ans then share your code

Comment: In lead we have Campaign lookup field. I used standard controller.. And got current record. I stored it in getters enters variable. Using that variable. I used <apex:inputfield value=" {!can't. Campaing}">how can I capture campaign lookup field I'd?!

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [documentation on the `Lead` object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm), there is no `CampaignId` field (nor any reference to `Campaign`. However, if you wanted to loop through the `Campaigns` a `Lead` is joined to, there is a `CampaignMembers` related list (see also [the documentation for the `CampaignMember` object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm)). You could, for example, do:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">
    <apex:relatedList list="CampaignMembers" />
</apex:page>
```

Or if you wanted more granular control over which fields to display:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Lead.CampaignMembers}" var="member">
            <apex:column value="{!member.Campaign.Name}" />
            <!-- other columns -->
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Campaign field on the lead cannot be queried and used. You will have to show the Campaign Member related list on your Page.